# Subgraph isomorphism and Anti-monotone property

Tags: bigdata, data-mining, dataset, graphs, similarity

While finding frequent subgraphs in single large graph, subgraph isomorphism (test) is not considered because its not anti-monotone. How and why subgraph isomorphism is not anti-monotone ?